# How does SortableJS `revertClone` option work?

Tags: javascript, user-interface, plugins, drag-and-drop, sortablejs

revertClone: `boolean` — revert cloned element to initial position after moving to a another list.

I can't get the difference between true or false in its [official](https://github.com/SortableJS/Sortable) [demo](https://jsbin.com/bifuyab/edit?js,output).

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If clone is enabled, it will show up when the user moves an element to another sortable.
By default, it shows up at the last position the dragged element was in in its original sortable list. However, with revert clone, the clone will show up at the drag start position of the dragged element in the original list, rather than the last spot it was in.

Comment: In this case , the top one 'foo' should be cloned at the bottom of its original list if revertClone===false, but it still appears at the top just like the revertClone===true case.
But thank you for clarifying the concept of revert clone, it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Not in a way you're likely to guess from its name.

TL;DR: **when dragging to a different sortable, should the original remain?**

Admittedly it's a difficult operation to name. If you're familiar with how dragging files in Windows Explorer behaves between drives, that is roughly similar.  That defaults to:

- *move* within the same drive
- *copy* between different drives

The *clone* is the duplicated object that appears to move during the drag. When `revertClone` is `true` there will remain two copies of the object after it is dropped into a different sortable container:  one where it was dropped, another where it came from. Otherwise there will remain only one copy.